# SMTP and Java email error

Tags: java, email, smtp

Hello I worked on this code to figure out how SMTP works with a java program and I got really far but I keep getting this error and I dont know whats wrong with it. It all seams to be what other similar programs that I looked at do but theirs seems to work.
It gets all the way down to the FROM line and then prints out this error

```
 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. n1sm21348109bkv.14 - gsmtp
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: 250 reply not received from server.

 at emailagent.EmailAgent.main(EmailAgent.java:73)
```

Any help with this would be appreciated
Thanks

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class EmailAgent
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

    // Establish a TCP connection with the mail server.
    System.out.println("Enter the mail server you wish to connect to (example:  pop.gmail.com):\n");  
    String hostName = new String();  
    Scanner emailScanner = new Scanner(System.in);  
    hostName = emailScanner.next();  
    Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, 25); 

    // Create a BufferedReader to read a line at a time.
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    // Read greeting from the server.
    String response = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(response);
    if (!response.startsWith("220"))
    {
        throw new Exception("220 reply not received from server.");
    }

    // Get a reference to the socket's output stream.
    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

    // Send HELO command and get server response.
    String command = "HELO alice\r\n";
    System.out.print(command);
    os.write(command.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
    response = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(response);

    if (!response.startsWith("250")) 
    {
        throw new Exception("250 reply not received from server.");
    }


   // Send HELO command and get server response.   
    System.out.println("Enter the name of your mail domain (example:  hotmail.com):");  
    String heloDomain = emailScanner.next();  
    String fullHeloCommand =  "HELO " + heloDomain + "\r\n";  
    System.out.print(fullHeloCommand);   
    os.write(fullHeloCommand.getBytes("US-ASCII"));   
    response = br.readLine();   
    System.out.println(response);

    if (!response.startsWith("250")) 
    {   
        throw new Exception("250 reply not received from server.\n");   
    }  

    // Send MAIL FROM command.  
    System.out.println("Please enter your e-mail address (example: me@myexample.com:\n");  
    String sourceAddress = emailScanner.next();  
    String mailFromCommand = "MAIL FROM:  <" + sourceAddress + ">\r\n";  
    System.out.println(mailFromCommand);  
    os.write(mailFromCommand.getBytes("US-ASCII"));  
    response = br.readLine();  
    System.out.println(response);

    if (!response.startsWith("250")) 
    {
        throw new Exception("250 reply not received from server.\n");  
    }

    // Send RCPT TO command.  
    System.out.println("Please type the destination e-mail address (example:  example@nova.edu):\n");  
    String destEmailAddress = new String();  
    destEmailAddress = emailScanner.next();  
    String fullAddress = new String();  
    fullAddress = "RCPT TO:  <" + destEmailAddress + ">\r\n";  
    System.out.println(fullAddress);  
    os.write(fullAddress.getBytes("US-ASCII"));  
    response = br.readLine();  
    System.out.println(response);

    if(!response.startsWith("250"))  
    {  
        throw new Exception("250 reply not received from server.\n");  
    }  

    // Send DATA command.    
    String dataString = new String();  
    dataString = "DATA";  
    System.out.println(dataString);  
    os.write(dataString.getBytes("US-ASCII"));  
    response = br.readLine();  

    if(!response.startsWith("354"))
    {
        throw new Exception("354 reply not received from server.\n");  
    }

    System.out.println(response); 


    // Send message data.   
    System.out.println("Enter your message, enter '.' on a separate line to end message data entry:\n");  
    String input = new String();  
    while(input.charAt(0) != '.')  
    {  
        input = emailScanner.next();  
        os.write(input.getBytes("US-ASCII"));  
    }  
        //End with line with a single period.  
    os.write(input.getBytes("US-ASCII"));  
    response = br.readLine();  
    System.out.println(response);

    if(!response.startsWith("250")) 
    {
        throw new Exception("250 reply not received from server\n");  
    }


    // Send QUIT command.  
    String quitCommand = new String();  
    quitCommand = "QUIT";  
    os.write(quitCommand.getBytes("US-ASCII"));  

    }   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The mail server you are attempting to connect to requires you establish a secure connection (TLS) in order to use mail services. Thats the error you are getting.

As far as the solution, I would highly recommend using the [JavaMail library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) as it provides much of this functionality out of the box, and has been robustly tested 'in the wild'.

Comment: I see, my goal with this is to try to figure out how smtp and TCP works with out delving into language specifics.

Comment: No problem, we've all been there. I would recommend using a mail server that doesn't require TLS or SSL to start off with, as the security handshakes add alot of complexity. As you get more comfortable with the protocol you can then move on to the more advanced aspects.

Comment: would you be able to suggest a mail server that does not need TLS or SSL just so I can have the feeling of yeah it worked?